# Having problems with resolve.root

Tags: webpack

Here is my directory structure:

```
src/
└── scripts
    ├── App.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── Main.js
    │   └── Navbar.js
    └── index.js
```

webpack.config.js and src/ are siblings and here is the resolve part:

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./src/scripts'),
    extensions: ['', '.js']
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to require('components/Navbar')?

Webpack says it can't resolve it.

Thanks.

EDIT:
The problem was that I was using 2.0.0-beta. I downgraded to 1.12.12 and it works.

Comment: I checked the configuration could you please try like this `path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scripts')`

Comment: I still get the same results

Comment: Could you check this http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root `root: []` is array there problem may occur from it.

Comment: I think array is only necessary when you want multiple roots. However, I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Hmm, sorry and my last chance if you are windows user, you may want to check this https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#windows-paths

Comment: I'm using Linux. I don't understand what could be wrong. Thank you anyway.